# Delete an SQL query result set

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete an SQL result set but it won't work:

```
DELETE FROM votes
WHERE id IN (
SELECT *
FROM votes v
LEFT JOIN comments c ON f.id = v.post_id
GROUP BY v.id
HAVING COUNT(c.comment) = 0 )
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? What is the error message you get? What exactly does "won't work" mean?

Comment: phpMyAdmin; and the error message is "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Comment: THere's a couple issues here...where ID in() subselect should never be *.  having count(c.comment) = 0 won't quite work either...I assume you are removing votes where there is no comment, in which case where c.comment is null not having count(c.comment).

Comment: @user1228907 - that error  "Operand should contain 1 column(s)"  means you subquery should be select id from...  not select * from ...

Comment: @Twelfth: even when fixing the syntax errors it won't work. MySQL has a stupid limitation that you can't use the table that you delete from in a sub-query.

Comment: @horse: hmm, so how would i go about the problem?

Comment: I somehow read this as SQL server not mysql.  Can I post 'upgrade to postgres' as an answer?

Comment: Can you create temp tables @user1228907?

Comment: not sure how to, sorry

Comment: Tried to answer for you...I beleive mysql uses select into syntax.  Comment on the answer if there's something not right there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true, that you can't use the same table from which you want to delete rows in a direct subselect, but with a little trick - a subselect on a subselect as derived table - you can do it:

```
DELETE FROM votes
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT 
        t.id
    FROM ( 
        SELECT v.id, COUNT(c.comment) cnt
        FROM votes v
        LEFT JOIN comments c ON f.id = v.post_id
        GROUP BY v.id
        HAVING COUNT(c.comment) = 0 
    ) t
);
```

I'm assuming that the rows without comments should be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You are close...2 changes

- a subquery in a where in() statement can only return one field.  Change select * to select v.id
- having count = 0  doesn't quite work in a logical sense.  If count = 0 then it's not there to delete anyway.  I suspect with the left join syntax you've used, you are going for votes that have 0 comments?   Right idea with the left join, but you want where c.comment is null (left join produces nulls...where c.comment is null means there was no comment found).

Of course this won't work due to mysql:

```
DELETE FROM votes
WHERE id IN (
SELECT v.id
FROM votes v
LEFT JOIN comments c ON f.id = v.post_id
where c.comments is null)
```

If I was stuck in MySQL...(sorry this is psuedo code, I haven't been in mysql long enough to get this exact in a text window.

```
select id
into #temp
FROM votes v
LEFT JOIN comments c ON f.id = v.post_id
where c.comments is null

delete from votes where id in (select id from #temp)
drop table #temp
```

Seems like a silly work around

Comment: K...this works as a sql-server or postgres solutiuon.   editting a mysql work around