# MySQL query with count and deleting the results

Tags: mysql

I have a list of all the zip codes in the united states. I need to delete the zip codes which do not appear in more than one county.

I have created the below query which is able to pull out all the zip codes I do not need, but now I need to delete them.

```
SELECT zipcode, COUNT(countyname) FROM enrollmy_healthr.`table 10`
group by zipcode having count(zipcode)>1;
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance you may have.

Regards,

Comment: This has been asked and answered before; see this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436236/delete-an-sql-query-result-set or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25591520/delete-duplicate-rows-having-count-greater-than-1-in-mysql

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing those links out to me. I have seen one before but I am having trouble translating and applying to my situation.

'code'  

again thank you for any further assistance. 

    DELETE FROM enrollmy_healthr.table 10  
WHERE zipcode, COUNT(countyname)

    (
       group by zipcode having count(zipcode) <=1
   ) tmp
;

'code'

Comment: Look at this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a96f8/1

Answer (score 1):

This way could help you

```
Delete from enrollmy_healthr.`table 10` where zipcode in 
(select * from (SELECT e.zipcode FROM enrollmy_healthr.`table 10` e 
group by e.zipcode having count(e.zipcode)>1) tmp )
```